# do_action not working in loop

Tags: hooks, actions

I've been using do_action to generate multiple action hooks in the loop. It seems unlucky for me the do_action not working.

```
function ltc_generate_input_fields($fields = array()) {

    echo "Hello World";

    if (empty($fields) || !is_array($fields)) return;

    foreach($fields as $field) {

        if (!is_array($field) || empty($field)) continue;

        $name = (array_key_exists('name', $field)) ? $field['name'] : '';
        $key = (!empty($name)) ? strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $name)) : '';
        $display_name = (!empty($name)) ? ucwords($name) : '';

        $type = (array_key_exists('type', $field)) ? $field['type'] : 'text';

        $id = (array_key_exists('id', $field)) ? $field['id'] : '';
        $id = (empty($id)) ? strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $name)) : $id;

        $classes = (array_key_exists('classes', $field)) ? $field['classes'] : '';

        ?>

        <div class="notebook-form-elements notebook-inputs">
            <div class="notebook-inputs-wrap">
                <label for="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $display_name ?></label>
                <input type="<?php echo $type; ?>" id="<?php echo $id;  ?>" class="notebook-features<?php echo $classes ?>" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="">
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php
    }

}

function ltc_generate_notebook_features_sections($sections = array()) {

    if (!is_array($sections) || empty($sections)) return;

    foreach($sections as $section) {

        if (!is_array($section)) return;

        $ltc_section_class = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-',$section['name']));
        $section_action = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_',$section['name']));
        $section_action = 'ltc_' .$section_action .'_content';
        $fields = (array_key_exists('fields', $section)) ? $section['fields'] : '';

        ?>

        <div class="notebook-section section-<?php echo $ltc_section_class ?>">

            <div class="notebook-section-heading">

                <h3 class="notebook-title"><?php echo $section['name']; ?></h3>

            </div>

            <div class="notebook-section-content">

                <?php do_action('ltc_before' . $section_action .'_content'); ?>

                <?php do_action($section_action); ?>

                <?php do_action('ltc_after' . $section_action .'_content'); ?>

            </div>

        </div>

        <?php
        if (!is_array($fields) || empty($fields)) continue;
        var_dump(has_action($section_action)); //return false
        var_dump($section_action); // return 'ltc_memory_content
        if (!has_action($section_action)) continue;

        add_action( $section_action, 'ltc_generate_input_fields', 5, 1);

    }
}
```

I used the bellow function to generate section.

```
function ltc_add_notebook_sections() {
    $sections = array(
        array(
            'name'  => 'Memory',
            'fields'    => array(
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Ram Type',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Memory Slots'
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Ram Speed'
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Expandable'
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Capacity'
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => 'Display Detail'
        );

    ltc_generate_notebook_features_sections($sections);
}

add_action('ltc_notebook_features_sections', 'ltc_add_notebook_sections', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `do_action` before adding it. Move `add_action` up, before HTML part.

Second, your action function `ltc_generate_input_fields' expects`$fields`value, however your`do_action` does not pass this parameter, so change it to

```
do_action($section_actions, $fields);
```

Comment: Thanks. it works.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with the code apparently:

1. `sections` array in the function `ltc_add_notebook_sections` has a syntax error.
2. `do_action_ref_array` function requires 2 parameters. You only seem to be supplying 1 in the `ltc_generate_notebook_features_sections` function.

The two functions should probably look something like this:

```
function ltc_add_notebook_sections() {
    $sections = array(
        array(
            'name'  => 'Memory',
            'fields'    => array(
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Ram Type',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Memory Slots'
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Ram Speed'
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Expandable'
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Capacity'
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => 'Display Detail',

        ),
    );

    ltc_generate_notebook_features_sections($sections);
}

add_action('ltc_notebook_features_sections', 'ltc_add_notebook_sections', 10, 1);
```

and

```
function ltc_generate_notebook_features_sections($sections = array()) {

    if (!is_array($sections) || empty($sections)) return;

    foreach($sections as $section) {

        if (!is_array($section)) return;

        $ltc_section_class = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-',$section['name']));
        $section_action = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_',$section['name']));
        $section_action = 'ltc_' .$section_action .'_content';
        $fields = (array_key_exists('fields', $section)) ? $section['fields'] : '';

        ?>

        <div class="notebook-section section-<?php echo $ltc_section_class ?>">

            <div class="notebook-section-heading">

                <h3 class="notebook-title"><?php echo $section['name']; ?></h3>

            </div>

            <div class="notebook-section-content">

                <?php do_action('ltc_before' . $section_action .'_content'); ?>

                <?php do_action_ref_array($section_action, $fields); ?>

                <?php do_action('ltc_after' . $section_action .'_content'); ?>

            </div>

        </div>

        <?php
        if (!is_array($fields) || empty($fields)) continue;
        var_dump(has_action($section_action)); //return false
        var_dump($section_action); // return 'ltc_memory_content
        if (!has_action($section_action)) continue;

        add_action( $section_action, 'ltc_generate_input_fields', 5, 1);

    }
}
```

That should probably fix it!

Comment: I'm sorry. It's the mistake when I copy the code to stackexchange. I edited the code, could please recheck this again.